# The process cannot access the files error using stream write

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, system.io.file

I am currently developing a system which logs the status of the system on a specific time and I am currently encountering the following error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Could I ask for your help on this? I am getting frustrated trying to find the best resolution on the error and been to different sites and forums looking for answers.

Really appreciate another pair of eyes which can check the error of the below code.

```vb
Dim strFile As String = "C:\System Logs\ErrorLogs_" & DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & ".txt"

Dim sw As StreamWriter

Try
    If Not File.Exists(strFile) Then
        sw = File.CreateText(strFile)
        sw.WriteLine("Start Log for today")
    Else
        sw = File.AppendText(strFile)
        sw.WriteLine("Last Cycle Time occured at-- " & DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine)
    End If
    sw.Dispose()
Catch ex As IOException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: You are not disposing the stream on an exception. Use [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement).

Comment: so you suggest to use using rather then if else?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting to use `using` rather than manual `Dispose`.

Comment: It does not seem to fix the issue, i have tried it but still same error occurs